# How to color the entire row using xlwt util of pyexcelerator

Tags: python, xlwt, pyexcelerator

The util talks about a function called this

```
style0 = xlwt.easyxf(
'font: name Times New Roman, colour_index red'
)
```

there is `color red` instead of `color_index` too .

Is there any provision to color the entire row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pattern: pattern solid
```

This can be used to add color to row...
then u can add the color u want..

```
pattern: pattern solid,fore-color "COLOR NAME"
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked this question on the python-excel forum and got a *comprehensive* [answer](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/python-excel/jTwq93AzLr0) there ...

By the way: `xlwt` is a fork of `pyExcelerator`, with bug-fixes and many enhancements. `pyExcelerator` is effectively abandoned.